# Oracle SQL* Loader : Loading Records Spread across Multiple Lines

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

```
Sample Data File : http://tny.cz/6e01a4cc
```

**Each Record;**

1. *Starts with the string* `***** Message dump *****`
2. *Ends with the string* `************************`
3. *Contains 12 columns*

   ```
     - Message ID           : 
     - Correlation ID       : 
     - Enqueue time         : 
     - Priority             : 
     - Expiration           : 
     - Delay                : 
     - Exception destination: 
     - Deq. attempts        : 
     - Sender name          : 
     - Message type   : 
     - Message state  : 
     - Data           :
   ```

   My control file looks like

   ```
     LOAD DATA
     INFILE 'address.txt'
     REPLACE CONTINUEIF NEXT PRESERVE (1:24) <> '************************'
     INTO TABLE temp_load1
     (
     COL1  char(4000)
     )
   ```

I am only able to store each record in a single column, with the above control file.

Is there any way, to parse the data file and load each values in their respective columns ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not able to give you a complete solution, but I'm pretty convinced that: you must use:RECORDS DELIMITED BY ************************

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look up the Stream Record Format in sqlldr - this is specifically there for data files containing records over multiple "lines".

[SQL Loader Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm#i1004951)

Look for "STR" for examples, also look for the section on Logical records.